# What will happen if I define more than one parameter but only pass in one parameter?

Tags: javascript

The function was defined as follow, but I don't know how the function will work if I pass in only one parameter and ignore the order.

```
function setCookie(name,value,path,expires){

    value = escape(value);
    if(!expires){
        var now = new Date();
        now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 6);
        expires = now.toUTCString();
    }
    if(path){
        path = ";path = " + path;
        }

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";expires = " + expires + path;
    }
```

Comment: try and find it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rest will be `undefined`.

This would have been a good thing to try out on your own before asking. You could have written a test program and tested it in probably the same amount of time it took you to write the question.

Answer (score 2):

Ommitting parameters to a JS function implicitly sets them to `undefined`. Extra parameters are ignored.

This is often used to provide default arguments (prior to ES6), like so:

```js
function foo(bar) {
  if (bar === undefined) bar = "default";
  console.log(bar);
}

foo("test"); // logs "test"
foo();       // logs "default"
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work for the most part, but you need to make sure each variable you use is defined. In the line, `function setCookie(name,value,path,expires){`, `name`, `value`, `path`, `expires` are all being defined right there. Its pretty much the same as `var name =...`, getting set to whatever you passed in. But if you don't pass anything in, it leaves out the part that defines `name` or the other variables, leaving those variables `= undefined`. When you have a variable equal to undefined, you can't use it in lines like `document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";expires = " + expires + path;`. What you need to do is make sure that each one exists, and if it doesn't, define it as, in this case, a blank string.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has very loose rules when it comes to arguments. You can make input infinite arguments that the function doesn't list (though they have to be accessed through the built in `arguments` variable).

```js
function showArguments() {
  for(var index = 0; arguments.length >= index; index++) {
    var argument = arguments[index];
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = argument;
    document.body.appendChild(p)
  }
}
showArguments('foo', 'test')
```

You can run a function asking for 10 arguments with 0, and only when you try to access a non-existent property will it error.

```js
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10) {
  console.log('no error, until you try to access something like length on the undefined argument');
  var length = arg1.length;
}
foo();
```

But because of this looseness, when you try to access arguments that ***should*** be there, undefined is returned. So in your case beside the first possible error of running `escape` on undefined, there should be no errors, and `document.cookie` will be equal to `name + '=' + undefined + ';expires = ' + now.toUTCString() + undefined`.

```js
function setCookie(name,value,path,expires){

  value = escape(value);
  if(!expires){
    var now = new Date();
    now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 6);
    expires = now.toUTCString();
  }
  if(path){
    path = ";path = " + path;
  }

  var cookie = name + "=" + value + ";expires = " + expires + path;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var p2 = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = 'name + "=" + value + ";expires = " + expires + path: ' + cookie;
  p2.textContent = 'name + "=" + undefined + ";expires = " + now.toUTCString() + undefined: ' + name + "=" + undefined + ";expires = " + now.toUTCString() + undefined;
  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(p2);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  return cookie
}

setCookie('foo');
```

To set a default for these undefined variables add `var foo = foo || 'default'`.